# No module named 'sympy'

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to import sympy and I get no module error. This is because I recently installed python 3.9 and when i search where sympy is stored it says python 3.8.6 how can I move the libraries to 3.9? Or can I downgrade idle? I am using ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: yeah both versions are installed:  Requirement already satisfied: sympy in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.7.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `pip` for python3.9. You can do that using following commands

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py python3.9 get-pip.py
python3.9 get-pip.py --user
```

Then you can use `pip` for installing `sympy`

In case if you want to take with the virtual environment path you can refer the above solution given by Anti_cse51, but you need to use `python3.9 -m venv my-project-env` for creating the virtualenv instead `python3`

Answer (score 2):

Create a virtual environemnt

```
python3 -m venv my-project-env
```

Activate the envirnoment

```
source my-project-env/bin/activate
```

then install sympy

```
pip install sympy
```

This was there would be no conflict with local packages

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question! The packages were successfully installed to the active environment but Idle still could not find them, the above answer however worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: afiz's soulition is more precise